# Declared NSString is taking the value in the form of NSarray

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I'm getting a weird exception as `"-[__NSArrayI integerValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b40bc0`
"I'm storing the value in NSString but its storing the values in the form of NSArray.In my application i've declared a variable of NSString as follows.

```
@property(nonatomic)NSString *phoneNumberSelected;
@synthesize phoneNumberSelected;
```

I'm fetching the value from an array which has phone numbers as follows:

```
phoneNumberSelected = [finalCustomerNumberArrayInViewControllerForFunctionalitiesOfBankViewController objectAtIndex:finalBankNumber];
```

When i do NSLog it shows as follows:

```
PHONE NUMBER SELECTED (
    "+93799700900"
)
```

But i dont want that to be saved with parenthesis because i've to invoke a phone call with the number i've got without parenthesis

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

I'm new to iphone development.Any help appreciated

Comment: Just because you declared something NSString does not make it one.  I can call myself "King of the Universe", but I doubt that many people will treat me like one (quite the opposite).

Comment: Then perhaps... **take the first element of the array?***

Comment: How you declare the variable `phoneNumberSelected` has some importance.  How you load the array `finalCustomerNumberArrayInViewControllerForFunctionalitiesOfBankViewController` is more important.  Can you include that code?  Also, I know it's Objective-C, but that is WAY, WAY, WAY too long for a variable name.

Comment: "finalCustomerNumberArray" should be a clue.

Comment: @HotLicks How so?  He's pulling out an object at an index from that variable.

Comment: @nhgrif - Point taken.  But the object he's getting is an array, as can be clearly seen by the bracketing `()` chars in the dump.

Comment: I agree.  We need to see the code in which he's filling the `arrayWhichHasWayTooLongOfANameAndWasImproperlyFilledWithNSArrayObjectsInsteadOfNSStringObjectsWhichHeClearlyIntended`...

Comment: If we're dealing with phone numbers I expect it might be an issue to do with using `ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues` from AddressBook instead of copying a single specific value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a crash because the object you are getting in not an of class NSString but of class NSArray.

do something like this :

```
NSArray *phoneNumbers = [finalCustomerNumberArrayInViewControllerForFunctionalitiesOfBankViewController objectAtIndex:finalBankNumber];

phoneNumberSelected = [phoneNumbers firstObject];
```